# Extract rows with same value across different dataframes

Tags: r, extract

I have the df `files` below, which contains many rows.

```
# A tibble: 2,320,079 x 2
   `files$File`                      `files$ID`
   <fct>                                 <int>
 1 oa_package/e6/58/176545.tar.gz     12929205
 2 oa_package/36/ba/176546.tar.gz     12929206
 3 oa_package/a9/0c/176547.tar.gz     12929207
 4 oa_package/46/44/176548.tar.gz     12938460
 5 oa_package/81/5e/193604.tar.gz     12975658
 6 oa_package/a5/8c/193605.tar.gz     12975657
 7 oa_package/f6/9e/193606.tar.gz           NA
 8 oa_package/93/a3/193607.tar.gz           NA
 9 oa_package/34/af/212687.tar.gz     14551903
10 oa_package/c5/d6/212688.tar.gz           NA
# … with 2,320,069 more rows
```

I also have a df `ID_1` which contains same datatype as `'files$ID'`, but which has only 186 rows.

```
# A tibble: 186 x 1
   ID      
   <int>   
 1 30237023
 2 12929205
 3 31475741
 4 32319557
 5 33842337
 6 28476099
 7 30103771
 8 12938460
 9 26417675
10 14551903
# … with 176 more rows
```

My question is: how do I extract all rows in `files` where `'files$ID'` has a value equal to `ID` row in the `ID_1` df?

As a first step I have tried to mutate `files` to include `ID` but this does not work since the # of observations must be equal.

```
files %>%
     mutate(row_3 = ID_1$ID)
```

result would be like this:

```
  `files$File`                      `files$ID`
   <fct>                                 <int>
 1 oa_package/e6/58/176545.tar.gz     12929205
 4 oa_package/46/44/176548.tar.gz     12938460
 9 oa_package/34/af/212687.tar.gz     14551903
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need a join here

```
library(dplyr)
files %>%
     inner_join(ID_1, by = c("files$ID" = "ID"))
```

Comment: when I do this, I am just getting the original `files` dataframe with the same number of rows

Comment: @aurelius_37809 do you need `inner_join`

Comment: @aurelius_37809 are you sure that there are no duplicates for the joining column.  I changed it to right_join.  When there are duplicates, it would match multiple rows at a time

Comment: `inner_join` worked, thanks! Realized the variable types were actually not equivalent  in environment

Comment: @aurelius_37809 before the join, just change the column types to same so that the `by` won't complain